# Connecting to a server hosted on a machine on the same network

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcpclient, tcplistener

This has almost certainly been answered a thousand times over, i genuinely can't find the correct answer, i'm quite the novice when it comes to networking.

Very simple, i want my client to be able to communicate with my server which is hosted on another machine on the same network.

`serverSocket = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 19407));`

`client.Connect("????", 19407);`

I have tried adding an inbound rule to the serving machine's firewall and making the client connect to my ip address, but still only achieve SYN_SENT when viewing netstat -n via the client machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your server is listening to `127.0.0.1` only. Try `IPAddress.Any` instead of loopback.

Comment: Champion, thanks matey.